# Laravel Detailed Error Page Lost

Tags: php, configuration, laravel, debug

I want to see all problems when a file can't loaded e.g. I used to do it but now I can't. The only thing I get when a problem occurs is

> Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

How can I change this to detailed error? How can I see which line has to be fixed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit `app/config/app.php` and make sure `debug` is set to `true`:

```
'debug' => true,
```

Comment: Thanks sir. This is a milestone for my Laravel career! :-)

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to go to this directory: `yourproject/app/storage/logs`.

Inside the logs folder. you will see a `laravel.log` file. This is like a stack trace which tells you how your programs is implemented and what specific type of error it is. You just need to copy the error message and search on Google.